# MySQL using bulk SQL statements with c#

Tags: c#, mysql, bulk-load

I realize that **LOAD DATA INFILE** can be used to load text/csv data. However, this seems to be limited to inserts. However, is there a way to get MYSQL to bulk import SQL files using c#.

My hope is to build up the SQL in a text file and then send it to my connection. Since this process is daily, I need it automated so that I do not have to have any user intervention once the program is started. It just takes too long **inserting** and **updating** when it can be done in bulk.

Comment: YSK: Even bulk imports do an insert for every row in the bulk import. It just dispenses with safeguards like being friendly to other system users to speed up the process.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried MySqlBulkLoader, it's just a C# class that wraps LOAD DATA INFILE.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html